# How uninstall system package?

Tags: android, package, system, uninstallation

Could anybody give me a code how can I uninstall system application (package)? I have root permission. And I need some example with package, coz names of apps in /system/app aren't available for me.

This command doesn't work for me and I don't know why:

```
su
pm uninstall com.example.package
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Please use other resources, such as http://android.stackexchange.com, for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: I assumed that there is some option available how can I do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rename there apk files, you found them in data/system I think the rename them to APP.apk_old

A lot of device got a problem with the rename command in linux so better use `mv`

Comment: I know this unix command but this is not what I need, I need to remove it programmatically.

Comment: then you crate a script programmatically on the device wich run as root. Search for Droidwall.apk it is open source and this app do it this way.

Comment: You don't understand me, I know unix command line and I know how to use mv or rm command, but I have only package name, not the name of apk in /system/app directory.